# Delete previous deployments in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, jenkins, deployment, rancher

I want to delete all my previous deployments[pods] after a new deployment is successful in Kubernetes. I can do it manually through the 'kubectl' command but want to write a script which automictically finds all previous deployments and deletes them. The deployment happens through a Jenkins pipeline. I wanted to know how I can do that. Whether I need to write it in the deployment definition file [deployment.yaml] or make it a stage in the jenkins file i.e. write groovy scripts to handle the deletion.

Comment: If you have a single file where all the resource yaml are written, then you could just `kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml` to remove everything at once?